# How to change an object in an array by finding the id's similar to id's in another array in JavaScript in expo/react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I've tried doing this by using an array methods and also looping, but It didn't work, it only somehow changes the first Id's object,

```
const [data,setData] = useState([
    {
      id:"1",
      isSelected:true,
    },
    {
      id:"2",
      isSelected:false,
    },
    {
      id:"3",
      isSelected:false,
    },
]);
const tasks = ["1","2"]
const selectPackage = async(tasks)=>{
    if(tasks){
        
        tasks.filter((tval,ti)=>{

            let newDataArray = data.map((data,i)=>{
                if(tval == data._id){
                    return {...data,isSelected:true}
                }else{
                    return data;
                }
                
                
            });
            setData(newDataArray);
            setPackageView(false);
            
            
        })

    }
    
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is:
Suppose you have an object like:

```
const data = [
    {
      id:"1",
      isSelected:true,
    },
    {
      id:"2",
      isSelected:false,
    },
    {
      id:"3",
      isSelected:false,
    },
];
```

And you're given some ID's of some objects in another array like:

```
const IDs = ["1","3"];
```

all I wanna do is change the value of isSelected of the corresponding id to be true.

Please help, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Can you please also tell me where can I learn more about these array methods? Send me a link or whatever, if you're free....thank you again.

Comment: there are plenty resources , for starters you can check here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Comment: Thank you so much man, I appreciate it.

Comment: sry i had to delete my comment because there was a mistake, i couldn't edit it, check the answer below

Comment: No problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
    id: "1",
    isSelected: true,
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    isSelected: false,
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    isSelected: false,
  },
];
const IDs = ["1", "3"];

data.map(item => {
  if (IDs.includes(item.id)) {
    item.isSelected = true;
  }
  return item;
});
```